# Ineffective generation of SQL queries when using expressions with LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

Consider the following code, where `dbContext` is a SQL Server database context and `Examples` is a `DbSet`:

```
this.dbContext.Examples.Take(5).ToList();
Enumerable.Take(this.dbContext.Examples, 5).ToList();
```

The first line works as expected and is converted to SQL in the following manner:

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Examples
```

However, the second line first fetches all rows and applies the `Take` operator afterwards. Why is that?

Since I am using expressions to build a dynamic lambda I have to use the second approach (`Enumerable.Take`):

```
var call = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    "Take",
    new[]{ typeof(Examples) },
    contextParam,
    Expression.Constant(5)
);
```

Unfortunately, the first approach does not work when working with expressions and the current architecture of the program forces me to build a lambda dynamically.

Why does the second approach fetches all rows and how can I prevent it in order to use it in expressions efficiently?

Comment: Why do yo uthnink it is ineffective? You get EXACTLY what you ask for. Enumerate, THEN filter. Nothing inefficient. This is like a guy driving 150km/h in a city and whining about the ticket he gets.

Comment: "Since I am using expressions to build a dynamic lambda" - no. THIS is called bad programmign. There are ways to hand in a lamba so there is NO need to use Enumerable. Also, you should return IQueryable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calling the same method. The first line is invoking `Queryable.Take`, not `Enumerable.Take`.

Since `DbSet` implements both `IQueryable<>` and `IEnumerable<>`, but `IQueryable<>` implements `IEnumerable<>`, the compiler treats `IQueryable<>` as a more specific type. So when it's resolving the `Take` extension method to call, it determines that `Queryable.Take(...)` is the right one, because it requires an `IQueryable<>` as the first parameter.

This is important because the `IQueryable<>` interface is what allows LINQ queries to be built as expression trees that get evaluated into SQL. The moment you switch to treating an `IQueryable<>` as an `IEnumerable<>`, you lose that behavior and switch to only being able to iterate over the results of whatever query had been built prior to that.

Try this:

```
Queryable.Take(this.dbContext.Examples, 5).ToList();
```

or this:

```
var call = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Take",
    new[]{ typeof(Examples) },
    contextParam,
    Expression.Constant(5)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It works because in the first statement

```
dbContext.Examples.Take(5).ToList();
```

You are invoking the `.Take(5)` on an `IQueryable` interface, on which the LINQ to SQL provider can execute proper SQL statement against the database.

If you need the query to happen on the database side, you have to construct the query on the `IQueryable` interface instance.

`Enumerable.Take` is an `IEnumerable` reference, the execution of the `Take` method will happen in memory, after you have fetch all of the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

"this.dbContext.Examples" does get all the data then Enumerable.Take filter and take the top 5 from it.

Comment: Not quite. `this.dbContext.Examples` is a `DbSet`, so by itself it will do nothing. However, when `Enumerable.Take` begins to iterate over it, that's when it gets translated into a query that gets all that data.